# Find messages by different criteria IMAP.search()

Tags: python, email, imap, imaplib

I use the **imaplib** library to work with emails. How can I search for messages with several parameters using `IMAP4.search()`?
For example, find all unread messages that came after a specific date, with the subject "Subject", from the sender "test@testmail.com".
I had an idea to make an 'one by one' search, I mean to search with next parameter in the result of the previous one, but:

```
    typ, data = con.search(None, '(UNSEEN)')
```

Result stored in list and I can't use `search()` function to that list. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`'UNSEEN FROM "test@testmail.com" SUBJECT "Subject" SINCE 17-may-1814'`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#section-6.4.4) should be what you want. All that is actually case insensitive, upper case is often used for keywords but it doesn't matter.

You'll find many, many examples in [older SO questions about this](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bimap%5D+search).

Answer (score 0):

Just a small addition to arnt's answer - it is possible to use list instead of string:

```
    search_list = []
    search_list += ['UNSEEN']
    search_list += ['FROM', '"%s"' % sender_name]
    search_list += ['SUBJECT', '"%s"' % subject]

    typ, data = con.search(None, *search_list)
```